# How to modify the input parameter of void method from the mocked method with mockito answer

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class A as

```
Class A{
 private static final String ANON_DIR             = "/webapps/worldlingo/data/anonymizer/";
 private static final String NO_ANON             = "noanonymize";

  public String first(String text, String srclang, Map dictTokens) {
      Set<String> noAnonymize = new HashSet<String>();
      second(noAnonymize,ANON_DIR + NO_ANON, "tmpLang","name");

      String value;
      if(noAnonymize.contains("test")){
      value = "test1";
      }
      else {
         value = "test";
        }

    return value;
}
```

where ANON_DIR and NO_ANON is static final value. This class has function first and function second .The first function has a calling method in it which calls second function. The second function is void function which takes static fields as parameter.

Second function is just the file read function with the path provided as

```
   public void second (Set<String> hashSet, String path, String lang , String type) {
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
          fr = new FileReader(path);
          br = new BufferedReader(fr);
          String Line;
          while ((Line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            hashSet.add(Line);
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          log.error("Anonymizer: Unable to load file.", e);

        } finally {
          try {
            if (fr != null) {
              fr.close();
            }
            if (br != null) {
              br.close();
            }
          } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Anonymizer : An error occured while closing a resource.", e);
          }
        }
      }

      }
```

Now I am trying to test the function first using mockito. I am trying update the passed  first argument (list parameter) i.e **noAnonymize** in second(**noAnonymize**,ANON_DIR + NO_ANON, "tmpLang","name");

```
    public void testfirst() throws Exception {
        Anonymizer mock = PowerMockito.mock(Anonymizer.class);
        doAnswer(new Answer() {
           public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
           List<String> args = invocation.getArgumentAt(0,List.class);
           args.add("a");
           args.add("b");

           return null; // void method, so return null
        }
     }).when(mock).readNoAnonymizeFile(Mockito.anySet(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString());

Method anonymizeNames = anon.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("anonymizeNames_test", String.class, String.class, Map.class);
String srcLang = "MSFT_EN";
Map mapTokens = new HashMap();
String result = (String) anonymizeNames.invoke(anon,"I am David",srcLang,mapTokens);

          }
```

PROBLEM:
  I am not able to mock the void second method to update list with value a and b. How can I have the mockto test case to update parameter in void method.

Answer (score 0):

When unit testing a class, you test it through its public methods. If you can't test the class sufficiently through its public methods, it needs re-factored.

In this case, you're trying to unit test a private method for an edge case that doesn't exist. Why even provide the constant as a parameter? Why not reference it directly in the private method and save passing an argument? Instead, you could write:

`fr = new FileReader(ANON_DIR + NO_ANON);`

**EDIT**

After Laxmi and I had a discussion we came up with a solution using constructor based dependency injection and changing the `void` method to return `Set<String>`. This let us test in isolation and mock easily.

Comment: My question is how can I update my list parameter in mockito. Even if I directly read the file as you suggested above, I still want to have my result in list to be updated in parameter.  how can I acheive this?

Comment: If you're trying to test private methods and can't get the coverage you need through the public methods in the class, it's bad design. Rather than trying to leverage the mocking framework to reach under the bonnet, consider rethinking the code. Perhaps `second` should be a `public static` utility method that you can test in isolation.

Comment: So what if I change the second method to public? How can I mock the second method to have its first parameter updated. I chaged my example to public

Comment: You wouldn't need to mock it. At the same time, you're opening up the visibility of the class and it's not a method I'd want exposed in that way. Give me a few minutes, I'll post an example of how I'd do it.

Comment: What's `value = word` - it doesn't compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185951/discussion-between-robert-bain-and-laxmi-kadariya).